# Prime Number Check 1-100 (C)

Tags: c, primes

The code below is to read input from the user to check if an int [1-100] is a prime number or not. (If out of range, will print "Done). If non prime, will output that to the console and the number divisible.

Right now this program is running correctly for 1-10 except for 3 and 9... Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num, i;
    printf("Number [1-100]:? \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    while(num>0 && num <101)
    {
        if (num==1||num==2)
            printf("Prime\n");
        for (i=2; i<=num/2; ++i)
        {
            if (num%i==0)
            {
                printf("Non-prime,divisible by %d\n",i);
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("Prime\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("Number[1-100]:? \n");
        scanf("%d",&num);
    }
    printf("Done\n");
}
```

Comment: Those are low numbers, why don't you just step through the code and see what it's doing?

Comment: "this program is running correctly for 1-10" - I doubt that. It prints "prime" for 1, whereas 1 is not a prime.

Comment: program states that 15, 21, and 27 are all "prime". and for the purpose of understanding this code 1 is prime to me

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure your code has appropriate whitespace. This will help you realize when things aren't lined up like you think they are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num, i;
  printf("Number [1-100]:? \n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  while(num>0 && num <101){
    if (num==1||num==2)
      printf("Prime\n");
    for(i=2; i<=num/2; ++i)
    {
      if (num%i==0)
      {
        printf("Non-prime,divisible by %d\n",i);
        break;
      }
      else {
        printf("Prime\n");
        break;
      }
    }
     printf("Number[1-100]:? \n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
  }
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

Now you should realize that your else statement happens on the first check! So when 3 is not divisible by 2, it prints "prime."

And then it breaks out of the loop.

And this happens for EVERY number. All your program is doing is checking to see if numbers are divisible by 2.

If you wrote "Odd" instead of "Prime" it would at least be correct there.

This is the kind of problem where setting a flag might be useful (there are other ways to do this, but this is one way).
So you could set a flag, say `int isPrime = 1;`

Now, if you find out that the number is not prime, you simply set `isPrime = 0;`.

Finally, at the end of the for loop (let me repeat: AFTER the for loop finishes), you need to check that variable.
And you can say,

```
if (isPrime == 1)
{
  printf("Prime\n");
} else
{
  printf("Non-prime.");
}
```

I'll let you figure out how to print the divisor :)

(For reference, correctly using the flag would look like this -- and for clarity I removed the 'feature' in which it continuously looped)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int num, i;
  int isPrime = 1;
  printf("Number [1-100]:? \n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  for(i=2; i<=num/2; ++i)
  {
    if (num%i==0)
    {
      isPrime = 0;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (isPrime == 1)
  {
    printf("Prime\n");
  } else
  {
    printf("Non-prime.");
  }
  printf("Done\n");
}
```

Comment: I had a flag to establish if it was prime or not and print accordingly, but I have changed the program many times

Comment: Do you see where your current error is, at least?

Comment: I'm assuming the error is with creating the for loop. Hot cold?

Comment: Okay, so I just added some additional edits. The final code example should work except I removed the infinite looping functionality, and it doesn't input the number's divisor. If you have more questions about that, let me know.

Comment: Your ERROR is that you are `break`ing REGARDLESS OF WHAT HAPPENS the first time in the for loop. If the condition is true, you break. If it's false, you break. So the for loop NEVER runs past `i=2`.

Comment: Yeah that works, I am changing it for the low int to know its a prime if the num==i (same value)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37289/discussion-between-wrhall-and-fish)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why 3 is behaving differently is that the for logic never reaches 3. For "(i=2; i <= num/2; ++i)", if num equals 3, then the i (being 2) is no longer less than 3/2, which is 1 (after rounding off). So, you should add "num==3" check to the  "if (num==1||num==2)".

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the entire range between 2 and num/2. You need a while loop and a prime flag.
Something like this.

```
    while(num>0 && num <101)
    {

        unsigned char prime = 1;    // set prime flag
        i = 2;
        while( i < (num/2)+1)
        {
            if(num%i == 0)
                prime = 0;
                i++;
            }
            if(num == 1)
            prime = 0;

        if(prime == 0)
            printf("%d is nonprime\n", num);
        else
            printf("%d is prime\n", num);

       prime = 1;
       printf("Number[1-100]:? \n");
       scanf("%d",&num);
    }
```